# Error installing scipy whl file using pip inPython 3.6

Tags: python, installation, scipy, pip, python-3.6

I am trying to install scipy for 3.6, but i get an error:

> "scipy.....whl is not supported on this platform."

I have been attempting to do this via my scripts and using pip install but i am unsure why this is not working.

Comment: OS? Full wheel name?

Comment: scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl on Windows 64bit

Comment: Did you install 32-bit or 64-bit Python 3.6? What was the command to install? Was it something like `C:\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe install scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`?

Comment: pip install scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: i have python 36-32 but im on a 64 bit system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 32-bit Python you need scipy‑0.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl. To install scipy‑0.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl you need 64-bit Python.